# Time difference of values? Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import os
import pandas as pd[enter image description here][1]
import datetime
df = pd.read_excel("m2.xlsx") # Imported excel file 
print(df)   # Printed the data output.
```

Numbers from 0 to 9 are present in each column. Date (in columns) and time (in rows) in excel sheet. Now I want the time difference of values for 8 and 0 present in the below data

```
 Dates            04:00 A.M(time)      08:00A.M(time)
13-08-2018           8                   1                
14-08-2018           3                   4                
15-08-2018           8                   9                
16/08/2018           7                   7                
17/08/2018           9                   8                
18/08/2018           5                   5                
19/08/2018           0                   6                  
20/08/2018           6                   3                 
21/08/2018           2                   5               
22/08/2018           0                   6
```

Desired result is something like the following:(Should show the time difference of values)
Time difference of value 8:

```
Date        Value    Time difference
13-08-2018    8         0 hrs 
15-08-2018    8        48 hrs
17-08-2018    8        100 hrs
```

Time difference of value 0:

```
Date        Value     Time difference
19/08/2018    0         0 hrs
22/08/2018    0         72 hrs
```

Sample data to load in python:

```
sample_data = [["13-08-2018",8,1],
            ["14-08-2018",3,4],
            ["15-08-2018",8,9],
            ["16/08/2018",7,7],
            ["17/08/2018",9,8],
            ["18/08/2018",5,5],
            ["19/08/2018",0,6],
            ["20/08/2018",6,3],
            ["21/08/2018",2,5],
            ["22/08/2018",0,6]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=sample_data, columns=["Dates","04:00 A.M(time)","08:00 A.M(time)"])
df["Dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Dates"])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please share the code for your best attempt.

Comment: Can you also explain what is the Value , on which basis you are considering `Time difference` difference it not clear though!

Comment: Values are the numbers stored in rows.

Comment: Dates             04:00 A.M              08:00A.M 
13-08-2018           8(values)            1 (values)              
14-08-2018           3(values)            4 (values)

Comment: Better to edit your Question for wide visibility!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need a function like this:

```
def Time_Difference(df,value):
    df_melt = df.melt(id_vars='Date',value_vars=['04:00 A.M','08:00 A.M'])
    df_melt['dummy_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_melt['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+' '+\
                                           df_melt.variable.str.extract("(\d+:\d+)")[0])
    df_melt['Time difference'] = 0
    mask = (df_melt['value']==value)
    df_melt.sort_values('dummy_date',inplace=True)
    df_melt.loc[mask,'Time difference'] = (df_melt.loc[mask,'dummy_date'].diff().fillna(0)/\
                                                                    np.timedelta64(1,'h'))\
                                                  .cumsum().astype(str)+' hrs'
    return df_melt.loc[mask,['Date','value','Time difference']].reset_index(drop=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['13-08-2018','14-08-2018'],'04:00 A.M':[8,8],'08:00 A.M':[8,8]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

Time_Difference(df,8)

        Date  value Time difference
0 2018-08-13      8         0.0 hrs
1 2018-08-13      8         4.0 hrs
2 2018-08-14      8        24.0 hrs
3 2018-08-14      8        28.0 hrs
```

---

**Explanation :**

Step 1: use melt to make columns `['04:00 A.M','08:00 A.M']` into single column:

```
print(df.melt(id_vars='Date',value_vars=['04:00 A.M','08:00 A.M']))
        Date   variable  value
0 2018-08-13  04:00 A.M      8
1 2018-08-14  04:00 A.M      8
2 2018-08-13  08:00 A.M      8
3 2018-08-14  08:00 A.M      8
```

Step 2: Creating `dummy_date` and adding values of `variable` column:

```
df_melt['dummy_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_melt['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+' '+\
                                           df_melt.variable.str.extract("(\d+:\d+)")[0])
print(df_melt['dummy_date'])
0   2018-08-13 04:00:00
1   2018-08-14 04:00:00
2   2018-08-13 08:00:00
3   2018-08-14 08:00:00
Name: dummy_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Step 3: filtering for the given `value` and getting the mask:

```
mask = (df_melt['value']==value)
print(mask)
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

Step 4: Finally, taking difference and filling na values and dividing by timedelta64. After this taking cumulative sum and changing data type to object and adding hrs to values:

```
df_melt.loc[mask,'Time difference'] = (df_melt.loc[mask,'dummy_date'].diff().fillna(0)/\
                                                                    np.timedelta64(1,'h'))\
                                                  .cumsum().astype(str)+' hrs'

0     0.0 hrs
2     4.0 hrs
1    24.0 hrs
3    28.0 hrs
Name: Time difference, dtype: object
```

Comment: Dates            04:00 A.M(time)      08:00A.M(time)
13-08-2018           8                   8             
14-08-2018           8                   8            
Code not working with the above data

Comment: @SrinivasG Update the question with that input and what is its output. So that I can change my code to fit the scenario. Thank you.

Comment: Code not working with the below data:  
Dates            04:00 A.M(time)      08:00A.M(time)
13-08-2018           8                   8                
14-08-2018           8                   8  
Out put should be: 
        Date         Value    Time difference
0 2018-08-13      8         0.0 hrs
1 2018-08-13      8         4.0 hrs
2 2018-08-14      8         24.0 hrs
3 2018-08-14      8         28.0 hrs

Comment: When the input is #df = pd.read_excel("m2.xlsx")  
Dates            04:00 A.M(time)      08:00A.M(time)
13-08-2018           8                   8                
14-08-2018           8                   8 

Out put is when I am using your code:
        Date  Value Time difference
0 2018-08-13      8         0.0 hrs
1 2018-08-14      8        24.0 hrs 
But my desired Out put should be as below: 
        Date  Value Time difference
0 2018-08-13      8         0.0 hrs
1 2018-08-13      8         4.0 hrs
2 2018-08-14      8         24.0 hrs
3 2018-08-14      8         28.0 hrs

Comment: ({'Date':['13-08-2018','14-08-2018'],'04:00 A.M':[8,8],'08:00 A.M':[8,8]}).   Please help me in getting the dictionary format after reading from excel in python as I have huge data to read from excel to python..

Comment: What I have Tried#import os
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel("m2.xlsx",index_col=0).to_dict()
print(df) # Unable to print in desired Dictionary format

Comment: @SrinivasG Use `to_dict(orient='list')`.

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel("m2.xlsx").to_dict(orient='list')
#df['Date']=df.Date.astype('str')
#df = pd.read_excel("m2.xlsx").to_dict(orient='list')
#df2=df[.to_dict(orient='list')]
#df['Date'].astype(basestring)
#df['Date']= df['Date'].astype(str)
#print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
Output:
{'Date': [Timestamp('2018-08-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-08-14 00:00:00')], '04:00 A.M': [8, 3], '08:00 A.M': [1, 4]}
But I need output in the below format without(Timestamp and 00:00:00)
{'Date':['13-08-2018','14-08-2018'],'04:00 A.M':[8,8],'08:00 A.M':[8,8]}